# Receive a wordpress notification when click on a specific link

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a way to receive a basic notification in the wordpress dashboard when a user clicked a specific link.

Do you know a plugin to do that ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

There are some plugins available to display a basic notification in the dashboard like [Dashboard Notes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dashboard-notes/). But might be It will not working like different notification for different pages.

You can create your own notification for every page so when user will visit that particular page then He will notify with a message.

Please follow [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-admin-notices/) link. It will help you to develop custom code by using some function to display a notice on the Page or you can generate Notices Via User Actions also.

Hope this guide will help you.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ahmed